# Chart.js V2 ticklines no grid

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm using ChartJs V2. Trying to have no horizontal gridlines but still have a little tick-line at the ticks. How is this possible? I'm using angular-charts to set the global options currently:

```
scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                gridLines: {
                    display: false,
                    drawTicks: true,
                }
            }],
        }
```

What I have:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/NGG8M6S.png]

What I want:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/XqEFOb6.png]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need for this are [Chart.js plugins](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#advanced-usage-creating-plugins).

They let you handle what is happening when events like the rendering or the update are triggered.

For instance, in your case, we want to draw again the ticks which were erased via the `display:false` attribute of `options.scales.yAxes.gridLines`.
We will then need the `afterDraw` event. Plugins in Chart.js are created like this :

```
Chart.pluginService.register({
    afterDraw: function(chart, easing) {
        // Your code in here
    }
});
```

---

Now that you know *how* to do, let's focus on *what* to do.

What we want is to redisplay the tick lines on the yAxes. But they were removed (*as I said above*).

We can't bring them back, but since Chart.js charts are using a [`<canvas>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API) tag, we can try to draw them once again.

To do it dynamically (*most I can at least*), we will need to loop in the different ticks of your **`y`** axe and, by also getting the height of your axe, we will be able to draw our own ticks.

---

Here is [a jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8w64h7ro/1/) (*improved by the OP*) with some explanation about what we must do and of course a fully working example, and here is its preview :

[image]

Comment: Unbelievable detailed response. Thanks! Made me believe in humanity again.

Comment: @Peheje Wow I'm glad I helped you that much ! You're welcome :)

Comment: With danger of appearing ungrateful ( I'M NOT THANK YOU ALOT :-) ). I found that the ticklines are just at tad bit off, and it seems to get worse the higher up the scale goes. I found it enough to add the index to the y entry in the loop. (entry * height / max) + idx. https://jsfiddle.net/8w64h7ro/1/

Comment: @Peheje Oh yeah, way better ! I haven't seen there was a difference at the tick 70 .. Sorry about this, I'm updating the link of my answer to your fiddle

Answer (score 4):

The gridlines `display` option must be set to `true` for the ticks part of the gridlines to be drawn.

To show only the ticks, use the `drawOnChartArea` option to turn off the gridlines on the chart.

```
scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
                display: true,
                drawOnChartArea: false,
            }
        }],
    }
```

EDIT:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vz2q1xgg/1/)